# External event trigger from a class c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window which has a DataGrid on it which in turn takes data form a bound list. The binding is timer controlled, i.e. every element in the list will only be there for 15 seconds and then gets automatically removed.

Once all the list becomes empty, the window is still up. How can the window be automated to close once the list becomes empty?

Comment: It's a very good textual explanation. Can we see a code?

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]. You should also read [these topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) which explain how to ask a good question.

Comment: Attach `WeakEvent` to the `CollectionChanged` event of your `ObservableCollection` and when you remove last element just call `Close` on the window ?

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to produce the code here. It is proprietary and I am under instructions to not reproduce any part of the code on a common forum.

Comment: What's the point of asking then? Also, you should provide a "minimal" example and not your full actual proprietary code.

Comment: I do apologise. I thought there would be a simple answer. In any case, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy:

- Set EnableRowVirtualization=true (it's also default setting)
- Handle UnloadingRow for your DataGrid, where you close the
  window, if the DataGrid's items source is empty

Comment: Thank you very much. This was what i needed. Thanks a lot